# jQuery-Fileupload & Django

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload

**tldr**: My file upload response is a HTML text, while JSON is expected, which is why I get a parsing error and the upload fails. Where/How does this error occur and how can I fix it?

**The longer version:**
I'm trying to integrate the jQuery-Fileupload into an existing Django app, but don't understand much about the automatic form creations by Django nor have I ever worked with jQuery or Ajax before.

To see if I could get it running without understanding, first I cloned this git repo (https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) and added it as a separate app to my existing Django project. Everything worked fine and I was able to upload files.

As for my existing app: I'm using a grid layout - and one of the cells already contains a working form. The others are more or less empty and I want to add the file upload into one of the empty ones.

When I copied all the stuff from one app to the other, on loading the html-page everything looks good (no errors on either python nor browser console), I can choose files and display the upload queue. But when I start the upload process I get an error, where apparently the rendered HTML-page is returned, while `jquery.fileupload.js` expects JSON.

I'm not sure what got lost or what I need to adjust in the code(s) when copying from app to the other or how a JSON response suddenly become HTML. Can anybody give me some pointers?

I'm using Python 3.5.1 (32bit) and Django 1.11.3 if it's of any importance.

Comment: do you upload file from new project to the first?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I'm uploading files from the hard drive. The two apps are unrelated, but managed by the same `settings.py` of the project.

Comment: may be you try to upload file from page rendered by second project to your first project, than you have trouble with cross site request. does it?

Comment: I removed the copied app, but I still get the same error :-(

Comment: show your views for file upload action

Comment: Sry for late reply (I went on vacation) - actually, your hint brought to my attention, that the error was indeed in the views! I used the wrong rendering and was now able to fix this. Thanks a lot!